# Adding command to LaTeX file using texify

Tags: miktex, texify

A program I am using spits out LaTeT tables in LaTeT files (`outreg2` command from STATA), which I run using `texify` to make pdfs of the tables. I crop these tables (using `pdfcrop`) and embed them elsewhere. However, the pdfs include page numbers, which prevent `pdfcrop` from cropping directly around the table. I need an automatic way to remove the page numbers before cropping. I want to insert the command `\pagenumbers{gobble}` into the LaTeX code to automatically remove the page numbers.

I believe

```
texify --pdf --texinfo="\pagenumbering{gobble}"  filename.tex
```

should work. It does not. No exception pops up, but the page number remains. I cannot find documentation anywhere showing examples of using the `--texinfo` option to splice LaTeX code into the file before running the LaTeX file to create a pdf.

How should I properly use the `texify` command? Or is there another way to conveniently splice in `\pagenumbering{gobble}` before running `texify`?

Comment: How about creating an intermediate `temp.tex` file that contains `\AtBeginDocument{\gdef\thepage{}}\input{filename.tex}`, which you can then `texify`?

Comment: On GNU/Linux, you could use Werner's suggestion directly -- e.g., `latex '\AtBeginDocument{\gdef\thepage{}}\input{filename.tex}'` -- without the intermediate file.

Comment: @jon: Same for Windows, but this seems specific to `texify`.

Comment: @Werner -- I wondered.  I had to look up what `texify` was....