# Adding a command to LaTeX file using texify

Tags: miktex, texify

A program I am using spits out LaTeX tables in LaTeX files (`outreg2` command from Stata), which I run using texify to make pdfs of the tables.  I crop these tables (using pdfcrop) and embed them elsewhere.  However, the pdfs include page numbers, which prevent pdfcrop from cropping directly around the table.  I need an automatic way to remove the page numbers before cropping.  I want to insert the command `\pagenumbers{gobble}` into the LaTeX code to automatically remove the page numbers.

I believe

```
texify --pdf --texinfo="\pagenumbering{gobble}" filename.tex
```

should work.  It does not. No exception pops up, but the page number remains. I cannot find documentation anywhere showing examples of using the `--texinfo` option to splice LaTeX code into the file before running the LaTeX file to create a pdf.

How should I properly use the texify command?  Or is there another way to splice in 
`\pagenumbering{gobble}` before running texify?

Answer (score 5):

This post contains a **Stata** tag and mentions the Stata user-written command `outreg2` 
(available running `ssc install outreg2`). Therefore, I offer two Stata-based solutions.

**Solution 1.**

The `outreg2` command, outputs LaTeX code that can be compiled with appropriate software. The original poster mentions

> I want to insert the command `\pagenumbers{gobble}` into the LaTeX code
>   to automatically remove the page numbers.

If that is all that is needed then I show below a complete example that uses `filefilter` to accomplish that.

```
clear all
set more off

* Example data, estimation and LaTeX code
sysuse auto

local filepath "/path/to/myfile.tex"

regress mpg foreign weight
outreg2 using "`filepath'", tex replace

* Introduce required text
filefilter "`filepath'" "`filepath'.2", ///
    from("\BSbegin{document}") ///
    to("\BSpagenumbering{gobble}\n\BSbegin{document}") replace

copy "`filepath'.2" "`filepath'", replace
erase "`filepath'.2"
```

The command `filefilter` just looks for

```
\begin{document}
```

in the generated `.tex` file and substitutes it for

```
\pagenumbers{gobble}
\begin{document}
```

Run `help filefilter` for details.

**Solution 2.**

Use the `tex(frag)` option with the `outreg2` command. This outputs a
`tex` fragment that can be included in some template `.tex` file using
the LaTeX `\input{}` command.

So use

```
outreg2 using "`filepath'", tex(frag) replace
```

and create a template `.tex` file along the lines of

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\input{file-created-with-outreg2}

\end{document}
```

This way, you can even create several `tex` fragments and include them all in the template `.tex` file.

Run `help outreg2` for details.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Roberto answered specifically for the situation of the OP. I want to try to give a more general answer:</sub>

*(For impatient readers: solution in lower part of this answer.)*

First let’s create a small testfile – `testfile.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
content
\end{document}
```

As the OP noted, does

`texify --pdf --texinfo="\pagestyle{empty}" testfile.tex`:

not produce any error, but the page number is still visible (I prefer `\pagestyle…`). Since Texify with the option `--pdf` calls internally PDFLaTeX, let’s see, what does happen with

`pdflatex testfile.tex "\pagestyle{empty}"`

The (not so) surprising answer is: Same result – no error, but also no success. But for (PDF(La))TeX another approach is well known:

`pdflatex "\pagestyle{empty}\input{testfile.tex}"`

Though, oops, no change. But this one works:

`pdflatex "\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{testfile.tex}"` **(*)**

If we try now to adapt this to Texify, we will with

`texify --pdf --texinfo="\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{testfile.tex}"`

get an error `texify: Missing file argument.` So I tried

`texify --pdf --texinfo="\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{testfile.tex}" testfile.tex`

(yes, the file is invoked twice). Surprisingly no error, but still no success. But there’s another possible parameter (cf. http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html) `--tex-option`, and with this replacing `--texinfo` I found …

### The solution

If a simple PDFLaTeX call as in **(*)** really is not enough and one wants to call Texify instead, this command prompt call works:

**`texify --pdf --tex-option="\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{testfile.tex}" testfile.tex`**

Once again: Yes, the file is intentionally invoked twice here.

Because this is rather long, one could put this in a batch file and later call this instead.

`test.bat`:

```
@echo off

texify --pdf --tex-option="\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{%1}" %1
```

Now in command prompt one has to execute:

`test.bat testfile.tex`

<sup>*At least it worked fine here in this way.*</sup>

---

*BTW: Thanks to Werner, because he brought up `\AtBeginDocument…` in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153241/adding-command-to-latex-file-using-texify/153268#comment349933_153241) to the duplicate question.*